# Permission denied on ipv6 Socket in Java

Tags: java, permissions, ipv6

I have a strange problem on ipv6 connection.

I write down a simple client server in Java, it works perfectly in ipv4 but when I try to use it with an Ipv6 address I receive a 
*"java.net.SocketException: Permission denied".*

If I try to run on the same machine client and server it works with ipv4 and ipv6 as well so i think that is a O.S. problem.

Some informations:

Ping6 works between machines
Iptables is stopped
O.s. is RedHat 6.2

Any ideas?
Thanks

Antonio

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: I'm quite sure, there isn't problem with code beacause also other application on ipv6 didn't works. I have made a snoop on the interface and i saw this icmpv6 as response from the endpoint Destination: Unreachable "Code: 1 (Administratively prohibited)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. There are two firewalls running as default on RHEL. I simply shutted down the IPv6 iptables.

*service ip6tables stop*