# IPv6 - java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: java, sockets, ipv6

I am new to ipv6 feature.

I am trying to connect from node 1 to node 2 via ipv6 address but I am getting "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied".

I have searched in forums and they suggest to use " -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true". But since I have to test ipv6 address, I have set this to "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false".

My sample program is as below which I am running from Node1.

```
public static void main(String...args) {
final Socket s = new Socket();
int port = 5122;
try {
  s.setSoTimeout(30000);
  s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("fcff:3:10:64:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd", port), 5000);
} catch (SocketException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And the ifconfig output from Node2.

```
[root@MAV ipv6_real]# ifconfig
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5C:26:0A:77:E4:FD  
      inet addr:10.10.64.86  Bcast:10.10.67.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: fcff:3:10:64:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:843294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:390846 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:351525171 (335.2 MiB)  TX bytes:74057040 (70.6 MiB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:e2e00000-e2e2000
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at com.vij.test.sockettest.main(sockettest.java:18)
```

OS: Fedora 16

Java versions tested: jdk1.6.0_33, jdk1.6.0_32, jdk1.6.0_25

I have also tried with -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true but the output is same.

It will be great if you can help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Does it work with sudo user?

Comment: nope. It does not with any user

Comment: Why are you using an outdated and end-of-life Linux distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved after stopping ip6tables as mentioned in the following question [Permission denied on ipv6 Socket in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257901/permission-denied-on-ipv6-socket-in-java?rq=1)